# how can i make my installer to check for invalid folder installation?

Tags: nsis

.Actually i have installed  different version of the software in the same computer so want to check  the folder for  both the version when user proceed for third version of installation. i am trying to use loop but the the installer is not working.Thanks in advance.

I have already 2 versions of same software installed in the same computer .I want when i will install the third version the script should check the path and it should not allow user to  install in the same path in which previous two versions are already installed

```
Function .onVerifyInstDir




  nsArray::Set array 1.6
  nsArray::Set array 1.7
  nsArray::Set array 1.8



  nsArray::Length array
  Pop $R0
  ;DetailPrint `array length: $R0`

  StrCpy $R1 0
  ${DoWhile} $R1 < $R0
    nsArray::Get array $R1
    Pop $R2
    StrCpy $tempregistry "$(^Name)_$R2"

    ;DetailPrint `MyArray2[$R1] is $R2`



 ReadRegStr $path  HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstal\$tempregistry""InstallLocation"  ;fetching installed location

   ${If} $path == ""


   ${Else}
   strCmp $path $INSTDIR 0 pathGood
   ;Abort
    IntOp $R1 $R1 + 1
   ${EndIf}  
  ${Loop}


    PathGood:
  FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Could you try explaining a bit more about what you are trying to do and post the code you currently have?

Comment: can you please help now i have added detail of my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps

1. Store ur product name or ur registry entry in a variable.
2. Store the path to be installed in a variable eg $path
3. Inside a loop check for the registry entry.

   ReadRegStr $pdt  HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\productname
4. If found,retrieve the value of the installed location and store it in a variable;
   eg $path1
   ReadRegStr $path1 $pdt "installed location"
   else proceed
5. ${if} $path == $path1
   messagebox mb_ok "Another version already installed in the path"
6. ${else}
   proceed
7. ${endif}